# how to set completion when define my own function

Tags: function, emacs, elisp

I wrote a function to insert some special characters in *"EMACS"*, which will ask to input the name and it inserts the corresponding special character.

Example: when I type "alpha", the function will insert `α` instead.

But when I type these characters, I found out that I cannot use auto completion. I defined alpha as `α` and beta as `β`, but when I type `al[Tab]` it just inserts a tab.

How can I define the auto completion for my function?

--Edit--------------------------------

Sorry, I'm still new to emacs and just started to write elisp function yesterday.

I just used a straightforward way to implement this function, using `interactive` with code `s` to read strings

That's why I wonder how to get the auto-completion done. Because I didn't find any tutorials about such things. Maybe it's for my lack in elisp knowledge to search the right answer.

Anyway, here is my code:

```
(defun sp-char (char)
"Insert some special chars."
(interactive "sInput char name: ")
(let ((funky-char))
    (setq funky-char
      (cond
       ((string= char "Alpha" ) "Α")
       ((string= char "alpha" ) "α")
       ((string= char "Beta" ) "Β")
       ((string= char "beta" ) "β")
       ((string= char "Gamma" ) "Γ")
       ((string= char "gamma" ) "γ")
       ((string= char "Delta" ) "Δ")
       ((string= char "delta" ) "δ")
       ))
(insert funky-char)))
```

I searched the read-string, but still confused how to get the completion done.

I'd appreciate it if you show me a little piece of code as example.

Comment: 1. There's `TeX` input method that does that. 2. How did you write the function? It is possible to generate completion list for functions like `read-string`.

Comment: Show us the read-string part of your function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's just Unicode chars you're after, there are other ways to
solve the problem:

1. There's `insert-char` bound to <kbd>C-x 8 RET</kbd>.
   It's got completion, so `*alpha` will get you everything
   with `alpha` in it.
2. If it's just Greek chars you're after, and you're on Linux,
   you can use `xmodmap` to redefine your keyboard:
   each key, like `w` has not two, but four states:
   normal, shift, Mod4 and Mod4+shift.
   I've it configured like this: <kbd>w W ω Ω</kbd>.
3. You could use `yasnippet` to accomplish this task.
   Like the second method, and different from the
   first and your method, it has a big advantage that it doesn't
   break your flow: you're not distracted by having to look
   at the minibuffer and/or read the possible choices -
   you just type what you wanted to type and expand.
4. `expand-abbrev` is similar to `yasnippet` but
   easier to add to, since each abbrev is just an element
   in the list, instead of a file. But it doesn't have
   fields/mirrors.

But it all really depends on what you're trying to do.

### UPD Corrected version of your code

This completion will exit as soon as the candidate is unique.

```
(defvar zz-minibuffer-map (copy-keymap minibuffer-local-must-match-map))

(define-key zz-minibuffer-map
  [remap self-insert-command] 'zz-self-insert-complete-and-exit)

(defun zz-self-insert-complete-and-exit (n)
  (interactive "p")
  (self-insert-command n)
  (ignore-errors
    (completion--do-completion nil 'expect-exact))
  (let ((candidates (completion-all-sorted-completions)))
    (cond
      ((null candidates)
       (backward-delete-char-untabify 1)
       (minibuffer-complete))
      ((eq 1 (safe-length candidates))
       (minibuffer-complete-and-exit)))))

(defun sp-char (char)
  "Insert some special chars."
  (interactive
   (list
    (let ((minibuffer-local-must-match-map zz-minibuffer-map))
      (completing-read "Input char name: " special-char-alist nil t))))
  (insert (cadr (assoc char special-char-alist))))

(defvar special-char-alist
  '(("Alpha" "Α")
    ("alpha" "α")
    ("Beta" "Β")
    ("beta" "β")
    ("Gamma" "Γ")
    ("gamma" "γ")
    ("Delta" "Δ")
    ("delta" "δ")))
```

Comment: I'd add abbrevs to the list for completeness.

Comment: Yes at first I just want to type some greek chars and some math symbols. Your solutions are good enough for typing those chars. I'll have a try. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

Use `completing-read` rather than `read-string` (or worse, `read-from-minibuffer`).

Comment: Thx I got it! One thing please, if I have two lists, one for greek chars and one for their names, how to get the corresponding char according to its name? sorry for the newbie question, I'm just started to learn elisp :D

Answer (score 0):

*This doesn't specifically answer your question, but it seems to apply to your use-case, so I'm posting it here.*

I've been using a keymap to insert Greek letters for some time now, and your question inspired me to make it into a package. And here it is:

[greek-unicode-insert](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/greek-unicode-insert)

Place it in your load-path, require it, and it will define a keymap called `greek-unicode-insert-map`. Bind it to something convenient

```
(global-set-key "\M-8" 'greek-unicode-insert-map)
```

and you can quickly insert Greek letters (and math symbols) by typing the prefix followed by the letter. `M-8 b` inserts beta, for instance.

It also supports upper case Greek letters (by holding shift) and alternative versions of some letters (by holding meta).

Answer (score 0):

`C-x 8 RET` lets you enter a Unicode character by name.  With **[Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles)** you can easily match any parts of the name.

Library [`ucs-cmds.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/UnicodeEncoding#ucs-cmds.el) lets you trivially define a command to insert any given Unicode character. You can bind such commands to keys to extend your keyboard.